# How to use associative arrays and match with indexed arrays?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

For the most part this code works, the issue I have is I don't know how to use the key of associative arrays and make sure that it matches with the indexed array. For example the code will  give a menu with cities but names like "Atlanta", but I need to match it in the airlines' file since it appears as ATL. They will not directly match. That is the main issue I have I dont know how to make the two arrays connect. 
Also another problem is the airlines file has extra tab spacing. I tried to fix it, but still its not perfect.

Really need help! Thanks!
Problem statement:

The two files,  `airlines` and  `cities`,   have    information about   airline flights from    selected    cities  to
some    destinations.       Your    script  should  determine   the list    of  cities  that    are possible    departures, and present a   menu    of  possible    city    names:

```
Please select the departure city:
1) Atlanta 4) Denver 7) Las Vegas 10) San Francisco
2) Boston 5) Detroit 8) Los Angeles 11) Syracuse
3) Chicago 6) Houston 9) Pittsburgh
```

After   the user    selects a   departure   city,   the script  should  display a   similar menu    of  possible    destinations.       After   selection   of  a   destination,    the script  should  display the list    of  all flights from    the selected    departure   city    to  the 
selected    destination.

Your    script  should  not hard-code   any of  the city    names   or  airport codes,  but should  extract them    from    the 
files   provided.

The objective is to display a menu for cities for departure and then pick from another menu for a destination. Then the two should be matched to find what flights exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
#cities=$1
#airlines=$2
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
PS3='Please select the departure city: '
cities=($(cut -f2 cities| sort -u))

select opt in "${cities[@]}"
do 
  case $opt in
     "$opt") echo "$opt"
         break;;
    esac 

done
cities=$opt
#need help with this part
declare -A city
city[ATL]=Atlanta
city[IAH]=Houston
city[DTW]=Detroit
city[LAS]="Las Vegas"
city[DEN]=Denver
city[PIT]=Pittsburgh
city[ORD]=Chicago
city[SFO]="San Francisco"
city[BOS]=Boston
city[SYR]=Syracuse
city[LAX]="Los Angeles"
city[DFW]=Dallas #not on list

airlines=($(cut -f4 $2 |sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\+/ /g' | sort -u ))

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
PS3='Select a destination: '
select option in "${airlines[@]}"
do 
    case $option in
     "$option") echo "$option"
          break;;
       esac
done


IFS=$'\t'
while read -r A B C D E F G H 
do
if [  $opt  = $D ] && [ $option = $F ]; then
echo "Flight: $A $B $C $D $E $F $G $H"
else
echo "$A $B $C $D $E $F $G $H" > temp 
check=($(wc -l temp))
#echo $check
if [[ $check = 0 ]]; then
 echo "Sorry no flights are available"
fi 
fi
done < $2
#rm temp
```

**cities file**

```
ATL Atlanta EST
DTW Detroit EST
IAH Houston CST
DFW Dallas  CST
DEN Denver  MST
LAX Los Angeles PST
SFO San Francisco   PST
MSN Madison CST
BOS Boston  EST
PIT Pittsburgh  EST
ORD Chicago CST
SAN San Diego   PST
LAS Las Vegas   PST
SYR Syracuse    EST
```

**airlines file:**

```
DL  Delta   490 ATL 6:30a   DTW 8:22a
DL  Delta   738 ATL 8:25a   DTW 10:10a
DL  Delta   1221    ATL 9:45a   DTW 11:33a
DL  Delta   796 ATL 12:25p  DTW 1:50p
DL  Delta   1818    ATL 3:50p   DTW 5:40p
DL  Delta   546 IAH 6:10a   ATL 9:06a
UA  United  1000    IAH 7:05a   ATL 10:03a
DL  Delta   1032    IAH 9:30a   ATL 12:19p
DL  Delta   490 DTW 9:25a   MSN 9:42a
DL  Delta   1202    DTW 12:20p  MSN 12:37p
DL  Delta   163 DTW 7:25a   ORD 7:44a
DL  Delta   485 DTW 10:10p  MSN 10:21p
UA  United  1015    ATL 6:15a   IAH 7:20a
DL  Delta   1681    ATL 10:30a  IAH 11:29a
UA  United  1199    IAH 8:15a   LAX 9:39a
UA  United  535 IAH 2:25p   LAX 3:54p
UA  United  1683    LAS 8:00a   SFO 9:46a
UA  United  6659    LAS 4:29p   SFO 6:09p
AA  American    4055    ORD 8:44a   MSN 9:39a
UA  United  1522    DEN 12:20a  SFO 2:00a
UA  United  1521    DEN 11:30a  SFO 1:10p
DL  Delta   101 ATL 11:55a  IAH 12:50p
US  USAir   246 PIT 12:05p  DFW 2:25p
US  USAir   101 PIT 12:15a  ORD 11:45p
US  USAir   2966    LAS 10:20a  SFO 11:54a
UA  United  2578    SFO 8:39a   SAN 10:07a
US  USAir   2967    SFO 12:25p  LAS 1:54p
AA  American    111 ORD 12:34p  LAX 2:50p
DL  Delta   432 BOS 8:45a   ATL 11:00a
AA  American    2345    LAX 11:40p  ORD 5:55a
DL  Delta   2006    SYR 5:53p   ATL 8:18p
AA  American    3542    ORD 3:00p   SYR 5:39p
```

Comment: You're supposed to fill in the `cities` array from the file, not hard-code it.

Comment: Does the `citiies` file really use space as the delimiter between fields, even though city names can also have spaces in them? Or does it use a different field delimiter, like TAB?

Comment: Yes but I talked to my professor and he said that I should go about it this way, but if you have a better approach that would work too

Comment: cities file just has spaces, airlines has tabs etc

Comment: Are you sure? The way the timezones are lined up looks like it's using tabs with 4-column tab settings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an indexed array, you need two associative arrays, one that goes from abbreviations to full names, and another that goes the other way.

```
declare -A city_by_abbrev
declare -A city_by_name
while IFS=$'\t' read abbrev name tz; do
    city_by_abbrev[$abbrev]=$name
    city_by_name[$name]=$abbrev
done < cities

while :; do
    select city_name in "${city_by_abbrev[@]}"; do
        if [[ -n $city_name ]]; then
            break;
        fi
    done
done

city_abbrev=${city_by_name[$city_name]}
```

You can use a similar technique to fill in the `airlines` array from that file. Then you can use these arrays to find the matching flights.